# CSS when I hover over text the hover effect disappears

Tags: html, css

When I hover over the box it makes the red color disappear even though I selected the div box that is holding the text and image. Any help would be appreciated! I am planning on swapping it out with a gradient but am using a red color temp. I am also planning on changing the image. (the original is grayscale but when you hover over it the image changes to include more color. That is besides the point, my only issue is making sure the gradient and colored image stays when I hover over the text. (looking this up the issue was solved by selecting the div that contained the boxes which I did; therefore I am unsure what to do. 
Edit2: Thanks the issue was solved by attaching the hover to the grid-item; this is my first site that I am coding and I appreciate all the help, hopefully I can contribute one day!

```css
  .grid-item {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  height: 23vh;
  padding-top: 2rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 1;
}

.grid-item .bg {
  width: 120%;
  height: 120%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1rem;
  top: .2rem;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, black, transparent 99%), black 20% url(images/woman.png) no-repeat;
  z-index: -1;
}

.grid-item .bg:hover {
  background-color: red;
  z-index: -1;
  .grid-item .bg2:hover {
    background-color: red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="main-message">
  <div class="action">
    <br>
    <h1><span class="redtext">LIVE<sup>&#9679;</sup></span> GUIDED WORKOUTS... FROM YOUR PHONE</h1>
    <a href="#" class="btn">GET STARTED </a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p class="shadowtext"><span class="redtext">50% Cheaper</span><br> than traditional gym trainers</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn2">LEARN MORE</a>
    <div class="bg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">

    <p class="shadowtext"><span class="redtext">More Choices</span><br> hundreds of instructors</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn2">LEARN MORE</a>
    <div class="bg2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.grid-item .bg:hover` --> `.grid-item:hover .bg`

Comment: Why are you using z-index on hover? Have you tried removing that and see?

Comment: You have `.grid-item .bg:hover {` with `.grid-item .bg2:hover {` inside, which translates to a .bg2 in a .griditem in a hovered .bg. That's not not setup.